# Extracting only certain words from string and ignoring words with numbers, etc

Tags: python, string

I've been thinking on this for a while, but have yet to come up with an efficient solution that does not employ a series of if - elif statements.

Let's say I have the following strings:

```
'Tennessee Tech'

'Auburn 1st'

'Southeast Missouri - Bottom of 2nd'

'Tennessee - Top of 3rd'
```

What would be the most efficient way of extracting just the team names from these strings?

In other words, my desired output would be the following:

```
'Tennessee Tech'

'Auburn'

'Southeast Missouri'

'Tennessee'
```

Side note: I do not believe there are any teams (for my purposes) that are comprised of three words (e.g. University of Arizona), however it would be nice for this instance to be satisfied as well.

The following code I have written only accounts for removing elements with numbers:

```
s = 'Auburn 1st'
string = s.split()
for j, word in enumerate(string):
    if any(char.isdigit() for char in word):
        del string[j]
team = ' '.join(string)
print(team)
```

Comment: Ok, I am relatively new to regex, but I imagine I would want it to identify a pattern such as " words until '-' or 'digit' " ?

Comment: Do you have a list of team names you are interested in?

Comment: How do your string look like? The first one (Tenessee Tech) seem to not have anything after it, but the others are followed by something.
If they are all followed by a hyphen you can split by hyphen and take the first part.

Comment: The list of teams will be in excess of around 300, and the way I have my current code structured it would be most efficient to perform this "stripping" for each iteration of the parent loop

In any case, the four examples above should capture all of the cases I am interested in (also the case where the team name may contain 3 words)

Comment: @CentAu Yes, there are cases where the string does not need to be edited, and that would be an example of that. And they are all not followed by a hyphen unfortunately, such is the case with Auburn...

Comment: Do the strings that need editing all share the format where the information after the hyphen is redundant and before is the team name? Or do you not know that?

Comment: @RickAhlf If there are no patterns, there is no way you can separate the team names unless you have a list of team names and search for those in the strings.

Comment: In the case that there is a hyphen with spaces surrounding it (e.g. Southeast Missouri - Bottom of 2nd'), then yes the information after the hyphen is not needed. However if the hyphen is not surrounded by spaces (e.g. Bethune-Cookman - Top of 1st'), then I would just want Bethune-Cookman returned. Let me know if that is unclear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly like you said in comments, use a regex to extract everything before a digit or dash

```
import re
new_string = re.split("(\s[-\d])", string_here)[0]
```

where `string_here` is the input to this regex.

*Edited to not split on the hyphen if there is not a space before it

Comment: Can you add a provision in the regex to capture hyphens only with space around them?

Comment: added to only catch if they start with a space, is that enough?

Comment: You're welcome! PS, if you do want space hyphen space, use this `re.split("((\s-\s)|(\d))", string_here)[0]`. It says look for `" - "` or `"[any digit]"`

Comment: Awesome, appreciate the tip!